# How to bind two columns row-wise of two different data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

```
#--------Get Sunday's from 2018-01-01 till today---------------------
d = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),Sys.Date(),by='day')
sundayList = d[weekdays(d)=='Sunday']
HolidayList = as.data.frame(sundayList)
colnames(HolidayList)[1] = "Holidays"

#---------Get Alternate saturdays 2nd and 4th------------------------
d = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),Sys.Date(),by='day')
saturdayList = d[weekdays(d)=='Saturday']
altSaturdayList = lapply(split(saturdayList, format(saturdayList, "%Y-%m")), function(x)
  na.omit(x[c(2,4)]))
altSaturdayList = as.data.frame(altSaturdayList)
altSaturdayList = gather(altSaturdayList)
altSaturdayList = subset(altSaturdayList,select = c(colnames(altSaturdayList)[2]))
```

Till here it's working as expected but I am not able to bind the two columns so  as to have the sundays and 2nd and 4th saturdays in just one data frame

```
HolidayList$Holidays = rbind(HolidayList$Holidays,altSaturdayList$value)
```

Any comments to improve the existing code will help.

I get the following error message.

```
> HolidayList$Holidays = rbind(HolidayList$Holidays,altSaturdayList$value)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Holidays, value = c(17538, 17544, 17545,  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 63
In addition: Warning message:
In rbind(HolidayList$Holidays, altSaturdayList$value) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

Comment: Just create a new dataframe? `df <- data.frame(values = c(HolidayList$Holidays,altSaturdayList$value))`

Comment: it creates a new data frame which is not the goal I need to append it in the existing dataframe HolidayList

Comment: then replace `df` with `HolidayList`

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice the assignment you made `HolidayList$Holidays`  It can be just `HolidayList <-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` after making the column names same

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(HolidayList, set_names(altSaturdayList, "Holidays"))
```

---

Or with `rbind`

```
rbind(HolidayList, setNames(altSaturdayList, "Holidays"))
```

Comment: couldn't find function set_names do I need any package?

Comment: @newguy you can use `rbind` as well after changing the column name.

Comment: see when I use HolidayList$Holidays = rbind(HolidayList, setNames(altSaturdayList, "Holidays")) it gives me error saying replacement has 93 rows, data has 63. While your answer is correct and to the point, I need to save the result in the HolidayList dataframe existing columns. Sorry I am still a noob at this.

Comment: @newguy Are you using it on the same data you showed as example (which is working fine with me).  If it is a different dataset with many columns, it needs to be specified

Comment: No it's the same dataset

Comment: I think they need `HolidayList = rbind(HolidayList, setNames(altSaturdayList, "Holidays"))` They are trying to store a dataframe result in a column `HolidayList$Holidays = rbind(HolidayList, setNames(altSaturdayList, "Holidays"))`

Comment: @newguy As I said, it is working fine for me.  Can you try it on a fresh R session.